# Use JWPlayer to play an Icecast stream

Tags: jwplayer, icecast, internet-radio

I want to play an Icecast stream using JWPlayer, below is the code I am using to embed and setup the player:

```
<div id='mediaplayer'>Radioplayer will be in this DIV</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  jwplayer('mediaplayer').setup({
    'flashplayer': './inc/player.swf',
    'id': 'player1',
    'type': 'sound',
    'width': '480',
    'height': '270',
    'autoplay': 'true',
    'volume': '60',
    'file': 'http://95.211.136.94:8039/stream'
  });
</script>
```

When the player is started, it works perfectly.
The stream is streamed by an Icecast server and when the player is started, it works perfectly. But when the current person leaves the stream and the next person joins the stream, the player starts to falter.

By pressing pause and play again, it works correctly again, but how can I solve this problem without restarting the player?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: found a plugin - http://www.yvoschaap.com/livestream/ - hope this works.

Comment: What do you mean by "when the current person leaves the stream and the next person joins the stream"?  What do you mean by "the player starts to falter"?  Be more specific.

Comment: Well, actually it is exactly like I say. We have a live radio. Every hour someone else connects to the stream. So the current person disconnects and the next person connects to the stream. When that person disconnects or the next person connects to the stream, it starts to buffer and to falter. You have to restart the player or refresh the site to solve the problem.

I have been looking for the solution, but all I can find is some strange Memory leak or something??

Comment: Can you be more clear?  What **specifically** do you mean by "someone else connects to the stream"?  Clients?  Encoders?  It isn't clear what end you are referring to.  Are you saying that you are switching encoding sources, and experience a delay at that point before data is received?  If so, that would definitely be expected, since you're not providing audio data during the switchover.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. My english isn't that great. Uhmmm "Are you saying that you are switching encoding sources" <Yup. This is what happens. When an encoders disconnects, it will automaticly play music (nonstop) and when another encoders connects, the nonstop stops playing and the stream will receive audio from the connected encoder.

Comment: Ahh, ok, that makes much more sense!  If there is an option to increase the buffer on the server end, I would start with that.  I don't remember if Icecast has this option or not.  Also, are both sources using the same sample rate and bit depth?

Comment: Yup, both sources use 128 bitrate. I already searched for a buffer option in ICEcast, without success. You can also listen to the site at 8PM. It will buffer/falter again at that time, when the encoders switch.

Comment: The bit rate of the compressed audio doesn't matter as much as the sample rate (probably 44.1kHz?) and bit depth per sample (16 bit?).

Answer (score 2):

I understand I'm grave digging here, but to anyone else wondering..

What he's trying to achieve on one mount point is pretty much impossible. We're talking about a brand new audio file being created and streamed.. either way you're going to have to refresh.

The solution with icecast really is to have one live mount point for listeners, In this case lets called it "/live". Then you need multiple mount points for other people to stream on, for example "/joe" & "/mossawi".

You need a constantly powered on machine (usually a server) to be streaming the main "/live" mount point, this will be access and listened to by the audience. Then on that server it needs to be scheduled to pick up and play the correct mount points for specific individuals at their allotted times. A radio playout piece of software usually plays that role, it also allows you to stream live music whilst no individuals are streaming (usually sold as 'auto dj' by hosting providers).

Feel free to hit me up with any other questions. I have been doing internet radio for the best part of 10 years.

Comment: Actually, he is using fallbacks at least he stated so in the comments. So it _should_ work fine but it's possible that some flash players do not handle it correctly. It is entirely possible to solve this with fallbacks and without an additional scheduling software that switches the streams.

Comment: Hi, please suggest me a audio player, To implement radio player.